# Best way to independant process to communicate

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have a series of independant bash shell running 1 python program.
I need to pass some status information between them (high frequency and small size).

Is there an efficient to communicate between those PID process  (using python) ?
I see those ones :

```
flat file  (issue concurrency).
Key value table like MongoDB.
```

Just wondering, if there are some packages in python,
simplifying this.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet are [Unix domain sockets](https://pymotw.com/3/socket/uds.html) and [Named Pipes / FIFOs](https://www.python-course.eu/pipes.php). For comparison you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475442/unix-domain-socket-vs-named-pipes). For simplicity you can use JSON as message format.